# Cannot intercept the method with byte-buddy with @Advice.Origin Method

Tags: byte-buddy

Using the following example, I am not able to intercept the methods call when I have `@Advice.Origin Method method` as an argument in my method.

```
public static void premain(String arguments, Instrumentation instrumentation) throws IOException {

  new AgentBuilder.Default()
        .type(ElementMatchers.nameEndsWith("Controller"))
        .transform((builder, type, classLoader, module) -> {
                 return builder.method(ElementMatchers.any()).intercept(MethodDelegation.to(AccessInterceptor.class));
              }
        ).installOn(instrumentation);
}

  @RuntimeType
  public static Object intercept(@Advice.Origin Method method, @SuperCall Callable<?> callable) throws Exception {
     System.out.println("intercept");
     return callable.call();
  }
```

If I remove `@Advice.Origin Method method`, the code starts working

```
  @RuntimeType
  public static Object intercept(@SuperCall Callable<?> callable) throws Exception {
     System.out.println("intercept");
     return callable.call();
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference between `@Advice.Origin` and `@Origin`. Advice can do less then delegation but inlines its code. You need to adjust your imports.